# Replace add to cart button with inquiry button?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

How do I replace add to cart button with an inquiry button in my wordpress ecommerce website? I know plugins which will do it in the single product page but I want it to be done everywhere, shop all, category page etc. Is there any way to do this without going for a premium plugin?

Comment: Can you please share the link of that plugin?

Answer (score -1):

The best plugin comes for Gravity Forms. If Problem comes then put a static button on the try Do it